# Как включить WebGL на QWebEngineView?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Пробую включить следующим кодом:

```py
self.browser = QWebEngineView()
self.browser.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebGLEnabled, True)
print(self.browser.settings().testAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebGLEnabled))
self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://webglreport.com/?v=1"))
```

Хоть и выводится True, флаг о то что WebGl Включён, но при заходе на сайт https://webglreport.com/?v=1 выводит сообщение

```
× This browser supports WebGL 1, but it is disabled or unavailable.

Sometimes this is the result of older video drivers being rejected by the browser. Try updating your video drivers if possible.

Also check out Get WebGL, or try installing the latest version of Chrome, or Firefox.
```

И передаёт только 2 параметра - платформу и юзер-агент. А не как в норме - все остальные. Подскажите что я делаю не так? И как правильно? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Видимо вам надо выполнить предписывающие рекомендации, 
так как у меня ваш пример работает без проблем.

Также посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517329/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-qt-5-9-under-windows

```
import sys

from PyQt5                    import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineProfile, QWebEngineSettings

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 

browser = QWebEngineView()
browser.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebGLEnabled, True) 
print(browser.settings().testAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.WebGLEnabled))
browser.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("https://webglreport.com/?v=1"))

browser.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]